# When should you create classes that are derived from IEnumerator/IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, generics, iteration, ienumerable

I do understand how both interfaces (`IEnumerator` and `IEnumerable`) work and what they are used for. However, I never quite understood when to create a class that is derived from one of these two interfaces. You can do a `foreach` loop on a list, on an array, and other generic collections as far as I am aware without having to create a class like I did in my code:

```
 class Program
{
   public static int[] array = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Enumerable = new Aninfiniteenumerator();
        foreach(var i in infiniteEnumerable)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"I is {i}");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
class Aninfiniteenumerator : IEnumerable<int> //Creating a class that is derived from IEnumerable
{  
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new MyInfiniteEnumer(Program.array);
    }

    IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new MyInfiniteEnumer(Program.array);
    }
}
public class MyInfiniteEnumer : IEnumerator<int> ////Creating a class that is derived from IEnumerator
{
    private int[] values;
    private int index = -1;
    public int Current => values[index];

    object IEnumerator.Current => Current;
    public MyInfiniteEnumer (int [] values)
    {
        this.values = values;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        index++;
        return index < values.Length;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        
    }
}
```

PS. I know that my enumerators are called "infinite enumerators" yet they are not infinite. So, as I have said, it is possible to do a `foreach` loop over a generic list/an array without having to create an `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerator` classes:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Car> vehicles = new List<Car>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            vehicles.Add(new Car(rand.Next(1970,2021), "Honda"));
        }
        foreach(var car in vehicles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(car.yearProduced + ", " + car.model);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            vehicles.Add(new Car(rand.Next(1970, 2021), "Subaru"));
        }
        foreach (var car in vehicles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(car.yearProduced + ", " + car.model);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(vehicles.Count());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
class Car
{
    public string model { get; set; }
    public int yearProduced { get; set; }
    public Car (int year, string model)
    {
        yearProduced = year;
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

Back to my question, I wrote the first code to be able to do a `foreach` loop over the `var` called "Enumerable". I only wrote this code for practice and see no practical use of creating classes that are derived from IEnumerable and IEnumerator. So, my question is, what are some situations where you'd have to create a class that is derived from one of these two interfaces?

Comment: `IEnumerable` (and its generic counterpart) are usually implemented by types that *are collections*. `IEnumerator` (and its generic counterpart) is a mechanism employed to do the actual "enumerate over" the collection. So if your type is a collection, you should implement IEnumerable, if your type *has* a collection, you usually don't, and the type that implements IEnumerator is usually an internal type, if you need it at all (also google "c# yield return")

Comment: _I know that my enumerators are called "infinite enumerators" yet they are not infinite_ So why do you call them infinite? :)

Comment: Potomy chto before that moi code was meant to infinitely write chisla

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good example of a custom structure that could use the enumerator is the **binary tree**.

A simplest tree would be

```
public class Tree
{
   public Tree Left { get; set; }
   public Tree Right { get; set; }
   public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

This definition can be used to compose arbitrary trees:

```
var root = new Tree()
{
   Left = new Tree() { Value = 1 },
   Right = new Tree() { Value = 2 },
   Value = 3
}
```

Note that my tree is balanced but actual trees don't have to be.

Now, how are you supposed to enumerate all values? It's not that easy, in each node you have to decide whether or not it has subnodes and when you are done at the node, you have to go back to its parent and explore all paths.

But the client code is not interested in whether or not it's difficult, it expects the code to be

```
 foreach ( var val in root )
 {
    // I want all values from the tree here!
 }
```

This is when the idea of enumeration starts to make sense. It's not only about simple, linear structures, like arrays or lists!

```
 public class Tree : IEnumerable
 {
     public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
     {
         if ( Left != null ) foreach ( var e in Left ) yield return e;
         if ( Right != null ) foreach ( var e in Right ) yield return e;
         yield return Value;
     }
 }
```

I hope this example sheds some lights on the issue.